# Remove NULL elements from list of lists

Tags: r, list, null

How do I remove the null elements from a list of lists, like below, in R:

```
lll <- list(list(NULL),list(1),list("a"))
```

The object I want would look like:

```
lll <- list(list(1),list("a"))
```

I saw a similar answer here: [How can I remove an element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652136/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-a-list) but was not able to extend it from simple lists to a list of lists.

EDIT

Bad example above on my part. Both answers work on simpler case (above). What if list is like:

```
lll <- list(list(NULL),list(1,2,3),list("a","b","c"))
```

How to get:

```
lll <- list(list(1,2,3),list("a","b","c"))
```

Comment: Maybe accept one of the solutions below?

Answer (score 31):

This recursive solution has the virtue of working on even more deeply nested lists.

It's closely modeled on Gabor Grothendieck's answer to [this quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25081427/980833). My modification of that code is needed if the function is to also remove objects like `list(NULL)` (not the same as `NULL`), as you are wanting.

```
## A helper function that tests whether an object is either NULL _or_ 
## a list of NULLs
is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))

## Recursively step down into list, removing all such objects 
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
   x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
   lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}

rmNullObs(lll)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "a"
```

Here is an example of its application to a more deeply nested list, on which the other currently proposed solutions variously fail.

```
LLLL <- list(lll)
rmNullObs(LLLL)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [[1]][[1]][[1]]
# [[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# [[1]][[1]][[2]]
# [[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: This is a great function!

Comment: @mrp -- Thanks! Glad I was able to pass on this handy template to someone else.

Comment: fyi, this probably behaves in ways one might not expect if your list elements are primarily data frame, since the `is.list` will capture and then unwind them. Simply adding an additional `&& is.data.frame(x)` should be enough I think.

Comment: @joran -- Thanks. Guessing you mean `&& !is.data.frame(x)`, right?

Answer (score 21):

Here's an option using `Filter` and `Negate` combination

```
Filter(Negate(function(x) is.null(unlist(x))), lll)
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
#
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "a"
```

Comment: I'm working with lists of S4 objects and this solution was the only one that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Using `purrr`

```
purrr::map(lll, ~ purrr::compact(.)) %>% purrr::keep(~length(.) != 0)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 7):

For this particular example you can also use `unlist` with its `recursive` argument.

```
lll[!sapply(unlist(lll, recursive=FALSE), is.null)]
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
#
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "a"
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you have lists in lists, you probably need to run `l/sapply` twice, like:

```
lll[!sapply(lll,sapply,is.null)]

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "a"
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a new package **[rlist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/index.html)** on CRAN, thanks to Kun Ren for making our life easier.

```
    list.clean(.data, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
```

or for recursive removal of NULL:

```
    list.clean(.data, fun = is.null, recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: What's the name of the package? Link?

Comment: sorry for the delay @not2qubit, the name of the package is RLIST as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix on Josh O'Brien's solution. There's a bit of an issue with lists of functions

```
is.NullOb <- function(x) if(!(is.function(x))) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null)) else FALSE

## Recursively step down into list, removing all such objects 
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
  if(!(is.function(x))) {
    x = x[!(sapply(x, is.NullOb))]
    lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
  }
}
```