# encoding a JSON expression from R with jsonlite or something else

Tags: json, r, dataframe, jsonlite

The API I'm using needs me to send it a `JSON` message like:

```
y <- '[{"a":1, "b":"select", "c":["A", "B", "C"]}, 
       {"a":2, "b":"text"},
       {"a":3, "b":"select", "c":["D", "E", "F", "G"]}]'
```

Notice that in the case `"b" : "select"` there is another variable `c` with the value being an array.

When I try running `fromJSON(y)` (in the `jsonlite` package) I get a `data.frame` where the 3rd column is a list:

```
> z <- fromJSON(y) 
> class(z)
[1] "data.frame"
> z %>% glimpse()
Observations: 3
Variables: 3
$ a (int) 1, 2, 3
$ b (chr) "select", "text", "select"
$ c (list) A, B, C, NULL, D, E, F, G
```

But when I convert it back to `JSON` *(which is the format I want to send to the API)*, the `c` variable appears where it shouldn't be.

```
[{"a":1,"b":"select","c":["A","B","C"]},
 {"a":2,"b":"text","c":{}},
 {"a":3,"b":"select","c":["D","E","F","G"]}]
```

Is there another R data structure that could reliably get me from a data frame to the original `JSON` message using `jsonlite` (or something else)? How would it work?

Comment: I think if you use `RJSONIO:fromJSON` and then `jsonlite::toJSON`  you get what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `jsonlite`, you can do as follows:

```
z <- fromJSON(y, simplifyDataFrame = F)
toJSON(z, auto_unbox=T)
```

In addition, consider following case where last `c` element is `["D"]`:

```
y2 <- '[{"a":1, "b":"select", "c":["A", "B", "C"]}, 
        {"a":2, "b":"text"}, 
        {"a":3, "b":"select", "c":["D"]}]'

z2 <- fromJSON(y2, simplifyDataFrame = F)
toJSON(z2, auto_unbox=T)
```

Result is this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":"select","c":["A","B","C"]},
 {"a":2,"b":"text"},
 {"a":3,"b":"select","c":"D"}]
```

This can be a trouble because the last `c` element is `"D"` not `["D"]`.

To prevent this, don's use `auto_unbox`. Use `unbox` carefully as follows:

```
z2 <- fromJSON(y2, simplifyDataFrame = F)
for(i in 1:length(z2)){
  z2[[i]][[1]] <- unbox(z2[[i]][[1]])
  z2[[i]][[2]] <- unbox(z2[[i]][[2]])
}
toJSON(z2)
```

Comment: Oh thats new to me too! Learned something :D

Comment: That is a great tip - I have been struggling with that issue for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a data frame to calculate things, you could do (the `rmNullObs` function is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539441/r-remove-null-elements-from-list-of-lists)):

```
z <- fromJSON(y)

is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))

## Recursively step down into list, removing all such objects 
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
  x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
  lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}    

z_list <- rmNullObs(as.list(as.data.frame(t(z))))
toJSON(unname(z_list), auto_unbox=T)
```

This converts the dataframe to a list, removes the NULL, and converts back to JSON.

If you don't need the dataframe, see @skwon's answer

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, but I'm getting: `{"1":{"a":1,"b":"select","c":["A","B","C"]},"2":{"a":2,"b":"text"},"3":{"a":3,"b":"select","c":["D","E","F","G"]}} ` from your code. I need the outer data structure to be an array.

Comment: forgot to `unname` the list, fixed it.