# Keep duplicated names in json object from jsonlite conversion of list

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

How can I convert a list to a json object using jsonlite keeping duplicated names?

```
z<-as.list(letters[1:3])
names(z)<-c("tmp","tmp","tmp")
toJSON(z,auto_unbox=TRUE)
```

results in

```
 {"tmp":"a","tmp.1":"b","tmp.2":"c"}
```

but I need

```
 {"tmp": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

Update: An easier solution is to bundle everything into a list

```
 my_list<-list()
 my_list$id<-"id"
 my_list$tmp<-c("a","b","c")
 toJSON(my_list,auto_unbox=T) # properly formatted JSON
```

Update: This question very nicely deals with the case of individually unboxing each JSON object [encoding a JSON expression from R with jsonlite or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792476/encoding-a-json-expression-from-r-with-jsonlite-or-something-else?rq=1)

Comment: Objects keys are unique. Fortunately JSON can represent arrays; is this representation sufficient for your needs? `{"tmp": ["a", "b", "c"]}`

Comment: Perhaps - is my desired json object not a proper format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21832701/139010

Comment: have updated my question as this would be the desired solution

Comment: An easier solution is to bundle everything as a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do the object manipulation yourself to reshape your object to get the correct JSON output. To get your desired output, you'd need a named list of arrays. Here's how you can convert your data to such an object

```
jsonlite:::toJSON(with(stack(z), tapply(values, ind, c, simplify=FALSE)))
# {"tmp":["a","b","c"]}
```

Basically `stack()` collapse the data into a data.frame and then we group the data into lists.

Comment: Nice. Then I can combine with other objects like this:  toJSON(list(id="blah",atts=jsonlite:::toJSON(with(stack(z), tapply(values, ind, c, simplify=FALSE)))),auto_unbox = TRUE)

Comment: `toJSON(split(unlist(z), rep(names(z), lengths(z)) ))` as a variation, or just `toJSON(split(unlist(z), names(z)))` if there is only one value in each list item.