# Remove null lists from the whole set of list and convert the list into a dataframe in r

Tags: r, list

I have a list and that contains elements as follow.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ip4"


[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "ip1"

[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "ip1"


[[1]][[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "ip6"

[[1]][[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "ip6"



[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[[1]][[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ip4" "ip6"



[[1]][[3]]
list()


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ip5"

[[2]][[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "ip5"



[[2]][[2]]
list()


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]]
[[3]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ip10"


[[3]][[1]][[2]]
[[3]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "ip11"


[[3]][[1]][[3]]
[[3]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "ip3"

[[3]][[1]][[3]][[2]]
[1] "ip3"



[[3]][[2]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]]
[[3]][[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "ip11" "ip3" 



[[3]][[3]]
list()

[[3]][[4]]
list()
```

I want to remove the lists which contains empty list and convert this list into a dataframe. So from the above list my desired output sholud be a dataframe that contains a list of vectors in its row. Dataframe myDf should be as follows.

```
myDF

col
ip4
ip1
ip1
ip6
ip6
c('ip4','ip6')
ip5
ip5
ip10
ip11
ip3
ip3
c('ip11','ip3') and to have list of dataframes where i will be having



    col
[[1]]ip4
     ip1
     ip1
     ip6
     c('ip4','ip6')

      col
[[2]] ip5
      ip5

      col
[[3]] ip10
      ip11
      ip3
      ip3
     c('ip11' , 'ip3')
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data

Comment: @akrun dput of my list is list(list(list(list("ip4"), list("ip1", "ip1"), list("ip6", "ip6")), 
    list(list(c("ip4", "ip6"))), list()), list(list(list("ip5", 
    "ip5")), list()), list(list(list("ip10"), list("ip11"), list(
    "ip3", "ip3")), list(list(c("ip11", "ip3"))), list(), list()))

Comment: The dupe link gives a way to remove the NULL.

Comment: Posted a solution below

Comment: @akrun thanks for the solution. If want the same in the list of of dataframes then by using rbind on each index of list i failed to achieve dataframe. Have edited my question

Comment: @akrun thnks for providing the solution. Adding little more to your answer for getting the list of dataframes i have added one line into your answer. All credits goes to you. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  You can edit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to remove the `NULL` elements using the function showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539441/r-remove-null-elements-from-list-of-lists)

```
is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))


rmNullObs <- function(x) {
x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
  lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}

lst1 <- rmNullObs(lst)
```

Then `melt` the new `list` ('lst1'), and `paste` the 'value' elements grouped by the other columns with `aggregate`, subset the `value` column.

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- aggregate(value~., melt(lst1), FUN= toString)['value']
d1
#       value
#1        ip4
#2        ip1
#3        ip1
#4        ip6
#5        ip6
#6   ip4, ip6
#7        ip5
#8        ip5
#9       ip10
#10      ip11
#11       ip3
#12       ip3
#13 ip11, ip3
```

For getting the list of dataframes we can use lapply.

```
lst_df <- lapply(lst1 ,function(x) aggregate(value~., melt(x), 
          FUN= toString)['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

A little while ago I wrote a generic function that allows transforming a recursive list, which I refer to here as a "tree", into any output object:

```
treeapply <- function(
    tr, ## tree
    fl=function(b,i,e) invisible(), ## leaf node function
    fi=function(b,i,e) invisible(), ## internal node function
    init=NULL, ## initial buildup object value or function
    b=if (is.function(init)) init(tr) else init ## buildup object
)
    unlist(recursive=F,lapply(seq_along(tr),function(i) {
        e <- tr[[i]];
        if (is.list(e)) treeapply(e,fl,fi,b=fi(b,i,e)) else fl(b,i,e);
    }));
```

With this function, we can very easily combine the leaf nodes into a list:

```
l <- list(list(list(list('ip4'),list('ip1','ip1'),list('ip6','ip6')),list(list(c('ip4','ip6'))),list()),list(list(list('ip5','ip5')),list()),list(list(list('ip10'),list('ip11'),list('ip3','ip3')),list(list(c('ip11','ip3'))),list(),list()));
treeapply(l,function(b,i,e) c(b,list(e)));
## [[1]]
## [1] "ip4"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "ip1"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] "ip1"
##
## [[4]]
## [1] "ip6"
##
## [[5]]
## [1] "ip6"
##
## [[6]]
## [1] "ip4" "ip6"
##
## [[7]]
## [1] "ip5"
##
## [[8]]
## [1] "ip5"
##
## [[9]]
## [1] "ip10"
##
## [[10]]
## [1] "ip11"
##
## [[11]]
## [1] "ip3"
##
## [[12]]
## [1] "ip3"
##
## [[13]]
## [1] "ip11" "ip3"
##
```

From which we can make a data.frame:

```
data.frame(col=I(treeapply(l,function(b,i,e) c(b,list(e)))));
##          col
## 1        ip4
## 2        ip1
## 3        ip1
## 4        ip6
## 5        ip6
## 6   ip4, ip6
## 7        ip5
## 8        ip5
## 9       ip10
## 10      ip11
## 11       ip3
## 12       ip3
## 13 ip11, ip3
```