# Keep list index number unchanged after removing NULL and character[0] in R

Tags: r

Is there any way in R to keep the index number same as before, while removing NULL and character[0] element from list. For example:

```
ld:
[[1]]
[1]"D2HGDH"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "TNF"   "IL6"   "CXCL1"

[[5]]
character(0)

[[6]]
character(0)

[[7]]
[1] "ICAM1"

[[8]]
NULL
```

Than removing NULL and character[0] using the following code.

```
#remove character 0 element
rmchar <- lapply(seq(ld) , function(x) ld[[x]][!ld[[x]] == "character(0)" ])

# remove null
is.NullOb <- function(x) if(!(is.function(x))) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x,      is.null)) else FALSE
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}

rmnull <- rmNullObs(rmchar)
```

so after running this the index is changed like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "D2HGDH"

[[2]]
[1] "TNF" "IL6" "CXCL1"

[[3]]
[1] "ICAM1"
```

which i don't want. I want the index number same as in list `ld`. So basically my desired output is looking something like:

```
[[1]]
[1] "D2HGDH"

[[4]]
[1] "TNF" "IL6" "CXCL1"

[[7]]
[1] "ICAM1"
```

Any way to do this? If yes than How?

I appreciated any help. Thank You.

Screenshot of my output.
    [image: The screenshot of my output after running the code]

Comment: The point is: if you remove some elements, indexes are changed (since index is the position of an element in the list)... so basically you can't...maybe you should think to use names instead of indexes...

Comment: use named list elements instead. `names(myList) <- paste0("X", 1:length(mylist))` These names will be fixed

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Richards's comments here is a solution for your case

```
ld = list(c("D2HGDH"), character(length = 0), character(length = 0), 
      c("TNF","IL6","CXCL1"),character(length = 0), 
      character(length = 0), c("ICAM1"), NULL)

# Convert the list to names 
ld <- setNames(as.list(ld), c(1:length(ld)))
```

Lines below copied from [R Remove NULL elements from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539441/r-remove-null-elements-from-list-of-lists/26540334#26540334)

```
#Remove null and character values 
is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))

## Recursively step down into list, removing all such objects 
     rmNullObs <- function(x) {
     x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
     lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
 }

newList <- rmNullObs(ld)
```

To get the indexes of list that were left use

```
names(newList)
```

Comment: But total I have 1900 list, how can i write the names in each list.?

Comment: Look at my solution, the names are automatically generated, not typed by hand, if what is required is numeric from 1 to 1900.

Comment: Still the index numbers are changed. Thanks

Comment: Did you use my code to remove null and character values?

Comment: Could you run the above code and show a screenshot here?

Comment: Yap surely i will show a screenshot here. Please wait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109554/discussion-between-lovedynasty-and-priyanka-nimavat).

Comment: Instead of `c(1:length(ld))`, we'd usually write `seq_along(ld)`, fyi. Regarding filtering, in the OP's case, `ld[ lengths(ld) > 0L ]` seems to work fine.