# Removing nested lists of length 0

Tags: r

I have a list of list of lists in R.  I want to remove the ones that are of length zero.

What I have tried so far is:

```
for (i in 1:length(test)) {
  keep <- rep(T, length(test))
  for (j in 1:length(test[[i]])) {
    if (length(test[[i]][[j]]) == 0) {
      keep[[j]] <- F
    }
  }
  test2[i] <- test2[i][keep]
}
```

Here is some example data (edited):

```
test <- list("Section 1" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")),
         "Section 2" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")))
```

I would like a way to remove the "A" list in both section 1 and section 2 since both are length 0

Comment: I assume this is a duplicate of the linked post. I can't be 100% sure since you don't provide sample data (screenshots are always a bad idea for sharing data). If the solution(s) from the dupe target do not solve your issue please clarify your post, include sample data and I'm happy to re-open.

Comment: @MauritsEvers i have added some sample data, thanks

Comment: `Filter(function(x) length(x) > 0, test)` works for the sample data you give.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, no need for the anonymous function: `Filter(length, test)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to wrap things up, and as per my earlier comment you can do

```
Filter(function(x) length(x) > 0, test)
#$B
#$B$`1x1`
#[1] "23"
#
#$B$`1x2`
#[1] "24"
#
#
#$C
#$C$`2x1`
#[1] "78"
```

or shorter still (thanks @Parfait)

```
Filter(length, test)
```

---

For a nested `list`

```
test <- list("Section 1" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")), "Section 2" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")))
lapply(test, function(x) Filter(length, x))
#$`Section 1`
#$`Section 1`$B
#$`Section 1`$B$`1x1`
#[1] "23"
#
#$`Section 1`$B$`1x2`
#[1] "24"
#
#
#$`Section 1`$C
#$`Section 1`$C$`2x1`
#[1] "78"
#
#
#
#$`Section 2`
#$`Section 2`$B
#$`Section 2`$B$`1x1`
#[1] "23"
#
#$`Section 2`$B$`1x2`
#[1] "24"
#
#
#$`Section 2`$C
#$`Section 2`$C$`2x1`
#[1] "78"
```

Comment: can this be used in a for loop to get blank lists out of each section? EX data: test <- list("Section 1" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")),
             "Section 2" = list("A" = list(), "B" = list("1x1" = "23", "1x2" = "24"), C = list("2x1" = "78")))

Comment: No need for an explicit `for` loop @user10256905; just wrap the `Filter` statement inside `lapply`, see my edit.

Comment: this requires all the empty lists to be in the same level, in that if you had `test$s = list()` the lapply function will not be able to capture this

Comment: @Onyambu Yes indeed. This is for the sample data OP gives in the comment above.

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate post in one way or the other; e.g. for recursive removal of NULL elements, see [Remove NULL elements from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539441/remove-null-elements-from-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1):

You can just write your own function:

```
check = function(x){
  m = lengths(x)>0
  if(is.list(x[m])) lapply(x[m],check) else x
 }

check(test)
$`Section 1`
$`Section 1`$`B`
$`Section 1`$`B`$`1x1`
[1] "23"

$`Section 1`$`B`$`1x2`
[1] "24"


$`Section 1`$C
$`Section 1`$C$`2x1`
[1] "78"



$`Section 2`
$`Section 2`$`B`
$`Section 2`$`B`$`1x1`
[1] "23"

$`Section 2`$`B`$`1x2`
[1] "24"


$`Section 2`$C
$`Section 2`$C$`2x1`
[1] "78"
```

Answer (score 0):

Claiming this is a duplicate requires the additional knowledge that lists containing only NULL items have length 0. Also requires assuming that `NULL` and `list()` are equivalent. Neither of those are necessarily obvious, although testing that proposition with `sapply(list(a=NULL), length)` shows the first to be the case. The second however appears not the case. Test: `identical(NULL, list())` returns FALSE, as do `identical(list(NULL), list())` and `is.null( list() )`.

The answer from Maurits Evers should succeed. This will also succeed:

```
 test <- test[ sapply(test, length) >0] # `sapply will return a logical vector

> test
$B
$B$`1x1`
[1] "23"

$B$`1x2`
[1] "24"


$C
$C$`2x1`
[1] "78"
```

Comment: `test[lengths(test)>0]`

Comment: Good one. I might have known at one time that there was a vectorized version of `length`, but if so had forgotten it.