# how to remove empty elements in a deeply nested list

Tags: r

I have a dataset that includes a number of deeply nested lists, which I am cleaning and reorganizing (and among other things, eliminating the nesting). I'd like to delete empty values from one of the nested lists so that I can compute the number of elements in that list accurately.

Some dummy data that reflects the properties of my real data:

```
x = list(1, 2, 3)
y = list("a", "b", "c")
z = list("")
w = list("1", "a", "", NULL)

merged_list <- list(x, y, z, w)

col1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "c")
col2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

df <- list(col1, col2, merged_list)
df
```

I tried using list_drop_empty from the vctrs package, which works fine when printing to the console, but as soon as I assign the output to a new variable, it only drops NULL values and not empty ones. So:

```
w_new <- list_drop_empty(w)
 w_new
```

returns "1", "a", "" rather than just "1", "a".

I've also tried to use the compact and discard functions from purrr, but haven't been able to get anything approaching a working function. And I tried to write a for-loop that would iterate through and set any empty values to NULL, but it simply returns a subscript error.

```
for (i in 1:length(merged_list)){
  temp_list <- merged_list[[i]]
    for (j in 1:length(temp_list) {
    if (merged_list[[i]][[j]] == ""){
      merged_list[[i]][[j]] <- NULL
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to fix this by initiating the vectors within the loop before referencing them, but it just set all values to NULL.

```
for (i in 1:length(merged_list)){
  merged_list[[i]] <- vector(2, mode = "list")
    for (j in 1:length(merged_list[[i]])) {
      merged_list[[i]][[j]] <- vector(2, mode = "list")
    if (is.null(merged_list[[i]][[j]])){
      merged_list[[i]][[j]] <- NULL
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to see output that converts w to ("1", "a") while it is still embedded in merged_list and df, without dropping rows like z that have a completely empty list.

It seems like there should be a relatively straightforward solution out there, but either I don't know the right function or I'm just not thinking of it. TIA!

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26540334/20002111

Comment: should the result for `z` be `''` or `NULL`? `rapply(df, function(x) if (any(nzchar(x))) x[nzchar(x)] else NULL, how = 'replace')`

Comment: @rawr the result for z should be NULL. Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: Thanks, Friede! I don't know why I couldn't find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, replace `""` in nested lists with `NULL`.

```
x = list(1, 2, 3)
y = list("a", "b", "c")
z = list("")
w = list("1", "a", "", NULL)

merged_list <- list(x, y, z, w)

col1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "c")
col2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

df <- list(col1, col2, merged_list)


# replace "" with NULL
new <- lapply(df, FUN = function(x){
  sapply(x, FUN = function(y){
    y |> purrr::modify_tree(leaf = \(x) if(is.null(x) || x == "")NULL else x)
  })
})
```

And then just use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26540334/20002111.

```
## A helper function that tests whether an object is either NULL _or_ 
## a list of NULLs
is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))

## Recursively step down into list, removing all such objects 
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
  x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
  lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}
rmNullObs(new)
```

Comment: Thank you! Strangely, when I replace "" in nested lists with NULL first, then run rmNullObs, rmNullObs fails to remove null observations. However, when I just run rmNullObs, it works as intended. I can see I have some studying to do to better understand the class of apply functions, but in any case, I have a working solution and I greatly appreciate your help.